# Why does not this AlertDialog dismiss in this situation?

Tags: android

I want to insert data from a text file into SQLite database :

```
public class SyncActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    private MessageDialogView dlg = null; // an AlertDialog showing a message
    private Patienter wait = null; // an AlertDialog containing an imageview showing an animation-list
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.synchro);
        ...
        dlg = new MessageDialogView(SyncActivity.this, getLayoutInflater());
        wait = new Patienter(SyncActivity.this, getLayoutInflater());
        ...
    }
    public void synchroniser(View view) { // called when a button is clicked
        wait.show();
        new RequestTask().execute("http://192.168.1.8/impots/data/syncro/webVersAndroid/parcelles.txt");
    }
    private class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> { 

        private String err = "";
        private boolean error = false;
        private String[] enregs;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... s_url) {

            enregs = new String[s_url.length];
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if(networkInfo != null) {
                if (networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
                    HttpURLConnection con = null;
                    BufferedReader reader = null;
                    for (int u=0; u<s_url.length; u++) {
                        String tmp;
                        String lines = "";
                        try {
                            URL url = new URL(s_url[u]);
                            if (url != null) {
                                con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                                if (con != null && con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                                    InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
                                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                                    boolean firstLine = true;
                                    while ((tmp = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                        if (firstLine) {
                                            firstLine = false;
                                            lines += tmp;
                                        }
                                        else
                                            lines += "\r\n" + tmp;
                                    }
                                    enregs[u] = lines;
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            error = true;
                            err = getResources().getString(R.string.errBadUrl);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            error = true;
                            err = getResources().getString(R.string.errAccessError);
                        } finally {
                            if (reader != null) {
                              try {
                                reader.close();
                              } catch (IOException e) {
                              }
                            }
                            if (con != null)
                                con.disconnect();
                        }
                    }
                }   
                else {
                    error = true;
                    err = getResources().getString(R.string.errNotConnected);
                }
            } else {
                error = true;
                err = getResources().getString(R.string.errNoNetwork);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (error) {
                wait.dismiss();
                displayError(err);
            } else {
                populateDB();
                wait.dismiss();
            }
        }

        private void displayError(String msg) {
            dlg.setTitre(getString(R.string.titreErrMsgBox));
            dlg.setMsg(msg);
            dlg.show();
        }

        private void populateDB() {
            String[] enreg = SpliterString.Split(enregs[0], "\r\n"); // get each record of "parcelle"
            db = new Db(SyncActivity.this).open();
            for (int p=0; p<enreg.length; p++) {
                Parcelle parcelle = new Parcelle(SpliterString.getColumnValueAt(enreg[p],0),
                                                 SpliterString.getColumnValueAt(enreg[p],1),
                                                 SpliterString.getColumnValueAt(enreg[p],2),
                                                 SpliterString.getColumnValueAt(enreg[p],3),
                                                 SpliterString.getColumnValueAt(enreg[p],4),
                                                 SpliterString.getColumnValueAt(enreg[p],5),
                                                 SpliterString.getColumnValueAt(enreg[p],6),
                                                 SpliterString.getColumnValueAt(enreg[p],7),
                                                 SpliterString.getColumnValueAt(enreg[p],8),
                                                 SpliterString.getColumnValueAt(enreg[p],9),
                                                 SpliterString.getColumnValueAt(enreg[p],10),
                                                 SpliterString.getColumnValueAt(enreg[p],11),
                                                 SpliterString.getColumnValueAt(enreg[p],12),
                                                 SpliterString.getColumnValueAt(enreg[p],13),
                                                 SpliterString.getColumnValueAt(enreg[p],14));
                db.insertParcelle(parcelle);
            }
            db.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Data inside the text file is just one row ( data are represented like a csv but separator is | ) :

```
1||010-01-02|PARC-0001|PARCELLE DROUDOUDOU|10||2000.00|500.00|1500.00||10, Av Place de l'Independance - CENTRE VILLE|01/02/2000|10/02/2005|CENTRE VILLE|
```

The problem is that the AlertDialog is never dismissed ! There is no error ! So what is wrong ?

**-- EDIT --**

```
public class Patienter extends AlertDialog {

    private View contenu;
    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = null;

    public Patienter(Context context, LayoutInflater inflater) {
        super(context);
        contenu = inflater.inflate(R.layout.patienter, null);
        setCancelable(false);
        setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(contenu);
        ImageView img = (ImageView)contenu.findViewById(R.id.imgWait);
        img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wait);
        frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();
        frameAnimation.start();
    }

}

public class Db {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "bdd_impot.bd", T_BIEN = "bien", T_PARCELLE = "parcelle", T_DECOUP_TERRIT = "decoupage_territoire";
    public static int VERSION = 1;
    private DbHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase bd;

    public Db(Context context) {
        DBHelper = new DbHelper(context);
    }

    private class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context,DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+T_BIEN+" (bien_code integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                    + "bien_ident text,"
                    + "bien_code_sig text);");

            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+T_PARCELLE+" (bien_code integer,"
                                + "decoup_terri_code text,"
                                + "dec_decoup_terri_code text,"
                                + "bien_ident text,"
                                + "parcel_denomination text,"
                                + "parcel_porte_ppale text,"
                                + "parcel_porte_second text,"
                                + "parcel_superfi_totale numeric,"
                                + "parcel_superf_batie numeric,"
                                + "parcel_superf_non_batie numeric,"
                                + "parcel_superf_plani numeric,"
                                + "parcel_adresse text,"
                                + "parcel_date_deb_construct text,"
                                + "parcel_date_fin_construct text,"
                                + "quartier_lib text);");

            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+T_DECOUP_TERRIT+" (decoup_terri_code TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"
                                    + "decoup_terri_nom TEXT);"); // rue
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+T_PARCELLE+";");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+T_DECOUP_TERRIT+";");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+T_BIEN+";");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public Db open() {
        bd = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        bd.close();
    }

    public void insertBien(Bien b) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("bien_ident", b.getBien_ident());
        values.put("bien_code_sig", b.getBien_code_sig());
        bd.insert(T_BIEN, null, values);
    }

    private int getBienLastInsertID() { // call this method after INSERT on table BIEN
        Cursor c = bd.rawQuery("SELECT last_insert_rowid()", null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            int id = c.getInt(0);
            c.close();
            return id;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public Parcelle getParcelle(int bien_code) {
        Parcelle p = new Parcelle();
        String[] columnsParcelle = {"bien_code","decoup_terri_code","dec_decoup_terri_code","bien_ident",
                                    "parcel_denomination","parcel_porte_ppale","parcel_porte_second",
                                    "parcel_superfi_totale","parcel_superf_batie","parcel_superf_non_batie",
                                    "parcel_superf_plani","parcel_adresse","parcel_date_deb_construct","parcel_date_fin_construct","quartier_lib"};
        Cursor c = bd.query(T_PARCELLE, columnsParcelle, "bien_code=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(bien_code)}, null, null, null);
        if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0 ) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            p = new Parcelle(c.getString(0),c.getString(1),c.getString(2),c.getString(3),c.getString(4),c.getString(5),c.getString(6),c.getString(7),c.getString(8),c.getString(9),c.getString(10),c.getString(11),c.getString(12),c.getString(13),c.getString(14));
        }
        return p;
    }

    public ArrayList<Parcelle> getAllParcelles() {
        ArrayList<Parcelle> parcelles = new ArrayList<Parcelle>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + T_PARCELLE;
        Cursor c = bd.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Parcelle p = new Parcelle();
                p.setBien_code(c.getString(0));
                p.setDecoup_terri_code(c.getString(1));
                p.setDec_decoup_terri_code(c.getString(2));
                p.setBien_ident(c.getString(3));
                p.setParcel_denomination(c.getString(4));
                p.setParcel_porte_ppale(c.getString(5));
                p.setParcel_porte_second(c.getString(6));
                p.setParcel_superfi_totale(c.getString(7));
                p.setParcel_superf_batie(c.getString(8));
                p.setParcel_superf_non_batie(c.getString(9));
                p.setParcel_superf_plani(c.getString(10));
                p.setParcel_adresse(c.getString(11));
                p.setParcel_date_deb_construct(c.getString(12));
                p.setParcel_date_fin_construct(c.getString(13));
                p.setQuartier_lib(c.getString(14));
                parcelles.add(p);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return parcelles;
    }

    public void insertParcelle(Parcelle p) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        if (p.getBien_code() == "")
            values.put("bien_code", getBienLastInsertID());
        else
            values.put("bien_code", p.getBien_code());
        values.put("decoup_terri_code", p.getDecoup_terri_code());
        values.put("dec_decoup_terri_code", p.getDec_decoup_terri_code());
        values.put("bien_ident", p.getBien_ident());
        values.put("parcel_denomination", p.getParcel_denomination());
        values.put("parcel_porte_ppale", p.getParcel_porte_ppale());
        values.put("parcel_porte_second", p.getParcel_porte_second());
        values.put("parcel_superfi_totale", p.getParcel_superfi_totale());
        values.put("parcel_superf_batie", p.getParcel_superf_batie());
        values.put("parcel_superf_non_batie", p.getParcel_superf_non_batie());
        values.put("parcel_superf_plani", p.getParcel_superf_plani());
        values.put("parcel_adresse", p.getParcel_adresse());
        values.put("parcel_date_deb_construct", p.getParcel_date_deb_construct());
        values.put("parcel_date_fin_construct", p.getParcel_date_fin_construct());
        values.put("quartier_lib", p.getQuartier_lib());
        bd.insert(T_PARCELLE, null, values);
    }

    public int updateParcelle(Parcelle p) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("decoup_terri_code", p.getDecoup_terri_code());
        values.put("dec_decoup_terri_code", p.getDec_decoup_terri_code());
        values.put("bien_ident", p.getBien_ident());
        values.put("parcel_denomination", p.getParcel_denomination());
        values.put("parcel_porte_ppale", p.getParcel_porte_ppale());
        values.put("parcel_porte_second", p.getParcel_porte_second());
        values.put("parcel_superfi_totale", p.getParcel_superfi_totale());
        values.put("parcel_superf_batie", p.getParcel_superf_batie());
        values.put("parcel_superf_non_batie", p.getParcel_superf_non_batie());
        values.put("parcel_superf_plani", p.getParcel_superf_plani());
        values.put("parcel_adresse", p.getParcel_adresse());
        values.put("parcel_date_deb_construct", p.getParcel_date_deb_construct());
        values.put("parcel_date_fin_construct", p.getParcel_date_fin_construct());
        values.put("quartier_lib", p.getQuartier_lib());

        return bd.update(T_PARCELLE, values, "bien_code = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(p.getBien_code()) });
    }

    public int getParcelleCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  count(*) as nb FROM " + T_PARCELLE;
        Cursor cursor = bd.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int nb = cursor.getInt(0);
        cursor.close();
        return nb;
    }
}
```

Even if I write just this line inside the onPostExecute then the dialog does not dismiss :

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) { // appellé automatiquement quand le tache background est terminé
    wait.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Whats your Patienter code

Comment: show us Patienter class

Comment: and also the `Db` class too.

Answer (score 0):

```
private class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... s_url) {




            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            pp.dismiss();

        }

    }
```

//=========================================//

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Patienter pp;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); // This needs to be done before
                                        // trying to findViewById
        final View vv = findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
        vv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pp = new Patienter(Main.this, getLayoutInflater());
                pp.show();

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        new RequestTask().execute();        
                    }
                }, 5*1000);

            }
        });

    }
```

Its working in my project.

please use wait.dismiss(); before if condition in onPostExecute() method.

Comment: With this code the user can dismiss the dialog even the `RequestTask` has not yet finished. Are you sure is that what the OP wants?

Comment: I want the user waiting until insert is finished.

Comment: please use wait.dismiss(); before if condition in onPostExecute() method.

Comment: So I must call the `populateDB` method inside the `doInBackground` then !

Comment: please change object name from wait to ppWait.

Comment: Why should I change it ?

Comment: because some time we use same name for other task also so may be. just for checking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73735/discussion-between-yogendra-and-pheromix).